# Is there any way to obtain all task of a process that have no candidate?

Tags: activiti

Using the Activiti API I can do something similar to the following: `processEngine.getTaskService().createTaskQuery().list()` to get all task of a process.

I can also filter all task in which a user can be a candidate (by group): `processEngine.getTaskService().createTaskQuery().taskCandidateGroup("somegroup").list()`

The idea is to use tasks without candidate as a task that anybody can perform.

How can I list all tasks where has no candidate?

NOTE: The group list can change at the future, then I cannot do a solution like "getting all tasks minus tasks with candidates"

Comment: Something like `processEngine.getTaskService().createTaskQuery().taskCandidateGroup(null).list()` but it launch a `ActivitiIllegalArgumentException: Candidate group is null`

Comment: And of course, It would be great if I can avoid to create a dummy group where put all users in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately all these queries get translated to SQL by Ibatis, which is why you are getting the IllegalArgumentException.

You have a couple of options:

1. use the managementService.executeCustomSql() method to build your own query. You can use the standard query definition from the Ibatis org.activiti.db.mapping.entity.task.xml mapping file.
2. Extend the Ibatis mapping by creating your own Ibatis mapping and associated resources.

Simplest would be option 1, most correct would be option 2.

Hope this helps,
Greg

Comment: Yes, I can always do a custom sql. But I was expecting that the API already has something to obtain a list of tasks without candidates.